# TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined at getFeaturedImage (related.js:24)

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming

I wrote code to load related posts into my WordPress single post. I have js that resize the featured image. I am getting an error when a featured image is part of the post.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined  at getFeaturedImage (related.js:24)
```

If no featured image is part of a post the related post everything works.

Note: I am using WP RIG to develop the site.

The following code is from the related.js file.

```js
// Get the featured image if there is a featured image.
function getFeaturedImage(postObject) {
        // If there is no featured image, exit the function returning nothing.
        if (0 === postObject.featured_media) {
            return "";
        } else {
            let featuredObject = postObject._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0];
            console.log(featuredObject);
            let imgWidth = featuredObject.media_details.sizes.wpRigRelated.width;
            let imgHeight = featuredObject.media_details.sizes.wpRigRelated.height;

            return `
            <figure class="related-post__image">
                <img 
          src="${featuredObject.media_details.sizes.wpRigRelated.source_url}"
                'width="${imgWidth}"
                'height="${imgHeight}"
                'alt="" ' +
                >
            </figure>`;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If featured image is part of a post then featuredObject might be undefined (according to your explanation).

If that's the case, Before you're trying to access the width & height of the object, check if it's undefined.

```
if(typeof featuredObject === "undefined") {
  return "";
}
```

So if it's undefined, this function will return an empty string, but if it's defined it would continue with the script.

(Consider sharing the output of `console.log(featuredObject);` in your developers tools as it might indicate what exactly isn't defined)

Answer (score -1):

I came accross the same error .. And I found the problème ..

it's because you don't have the Thumbnails alredy at the good size..
in the cours you create a new Thumbnails size but you need to Regenerate Thumbnails to have them ... use a plugin to Regenerate Thumbnails.. and it's works ...

Comment: Could you add more details like what plugin specifically and the code that fixes the problem?

Comment: I use a plugin like this one : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

no code need to be changed. 

it's juste that you call a thumbnails how dosen't exist.. that wy you have this error.
regenerate the thumbnails and now it's work